# Store procedure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

Buen día,

Tengo el cuerpo de un SP, se supone que solo debe realizar 3 select, estos valores ya estan declarados: @SectorId INT, @PesId INT, @OffenderConductId int

```
USE [Supervision]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_TIS]    Script Date: 24/09/2020 10:16:22 a. m. ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[SP_TIS]

@OficioEmplazamiento VARCHAR

as begin

DECLARE @SectorId INT, @PesId INT, @OffenderConductId int

SET @SectorId = (SELECT Pts.OffenderConduct.SectorId  FROM Pts.OffenderConduct join 
Pts.OffenderConductDocument on Pts.OffenderConduct.OffenderConductDocumentId = Pts.OffenderConductDocument.Id
WHERE Pts.OffenderConductDocument.OfficeNumber = @OficioEmplazamiento)


SET @PesId = (SELECT Pts.OffenderConduct.EntityId  FROM Pts.OffenderConduct join 
Pts.OffenderConductDocument on Pts.OffenderConductDocument.Id = Pts.OffenderConduct.OffenderConductDocumentId 
WHERE @OficioEmplazamiento = Pts.OffenderConductDocument.OfficeNumber)


SET @OffenderConductId = (SELECT Pts.OffenderConductDocument.Id  FROM Pts.OffenderConductDocument join 
Pts.OffenderConduct on Pts.OffenderConductDocument.Id = Pts.OffenderConduct.OffenderConductDocumentId 
WHERE @OficioEmplazamiento = Pts.OffenderConductDocument.OfficeNumber)


SELECT @SectorId, @PesId, @OffenderConductId

end
```

y seteados, cuando trato de realizar un select a @SectorId, @PesId, @OffenderConductId no me trae ningun resultado, es como si no encontrara el dato.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cabe mencionar que ya probe los select y la estructura esta bien si llama los datos que le pido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me pregunto si algo me falta...

gracias

Answer (score 5):

El error está en la declaración del parámetro `@OficioEmplazamiento`, es de tipo `varchar` pero no especifica la longitud, por eso solo toma un caracter del código que es la longitud por defecto del varchar.

```
@OficioEmplazamiento VARCHAR(longitud)
```